# Can this be a valid complete answer for this question?

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

Assume $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are linearly independent functions.Show that the addition to the set of one of these functions say, $f_1$ makes the new set linearly dependent.
I show that $(1)f_1+(-1)f_1+(0)f_2+(0)f_3=0$.
Is it enough? Is that all that is asked here?

Comment: I would add a few more words, but, yes, that is correct.

Comment: Yes, this would suffice, as not all coefficients are 0. The question does seem a bit odd though, as typically in a set of elements, repeated elements are excluded from the set.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect. The *set* $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}\cup \{f_1\}$ is just $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ again and so still linearly independent. That is one reason why I am always extremely unhappy when people introduce the concept of  linear dependence in terms of *sets* of vectors. One should rather use *families* of vectors.

If we silently interpret each occurence of "set" as "family" in the problem statement, then everything is correct.

Comment: I think you interprete „add g1 to the set“ Not in the way the Op does.